Aluminum and Copper Wiring
I just bought a house built in 1968. When looking in the main panel you can see aluminum wiring, which makes sense given the year built. But when I started opening the outlets, they had copper wiring. Has anyone come across this? I was expecting the entire house to wired in aluminum. My guess is there is an aluminum/copper connection in the attic (I’m searching for it), and I’m having an electrician out later next week. I’m just curious if anyone has come across this or what their thoughts are.
Also to note, from the top of the panel through the garage and into the attic, there are about 7-8 white wires that say Alumaflex on them.



Please post pictures of your (opened) panel. There are multiple different options. Aluminum for heavy feeders only is still standard and has never been a problem. Aluminum branch circuit wiring is a completely different deal. And there are multiple ways of retrofitting branch wiring.

From Wikipedia "In North American residential construction, aluminum wire was used for wiring entire houses for a short time from the 1960s to the mid-1970s during a period of high copper prices." As Ecnerwal pointed out, aluminum feeder wires are still quite common since aluminum is quite a bit cheaper than copper, but branch circuit wiring is normally done in copper as you found in your receptacles.

My 1990-built house had aluminum for HVAC, copper for everything else.

What is your question? Asking for "thoughts" makes your post off topic here. Please see [ask], and take the [tour]. Revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Note that aluminum has been discussed quite a bit already. Try searching.
